# Using union but retrieve only values of duplicate name for a column

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Table A

```
ID      Name        Age     Sex
====    ========    =====   =====
1       Jack        20      Male
2       James       18      Male
3       Jane        17      Female
4       Jessy       16      Female
5       John        34      Male
```

Table B

```
ID      Name        Age     Sex
====    =========   =====   =====
1       Jack        21      Male
2       James       18      Male
3       Jane        17      Male
4       Jenna       17      Famale
5       John        34      Male        
6       John        34      Male
```

I use

```
select ID, Name, Age, Sex
from Table A
union
select ID, Name, Age, Sex
from Table B
```

I get the following result

```
ID      Name        Age     Sex
====    =========   =====   =====
1       Jack        20      Male
1       Jack        21      Male
2       James       18      Male
3       Jane        17      Female
3       Jane        17      Male
4       Jessy       16      Female
4       Jenna       17      Famale
5       John        34      Male
6       John        34      Male
```

But what i want is I want my expected result to be duplicate of name only. Incase no duplicate name do not show in the result like

```
ID      Name        Age     Sex
====    =========   =====   =====
1       Jack        20      Male
1       Jack        21      Male
3       Jane        17      Female
3       Jane        17      Male
5       John        34      Male
6       John        34      Male
```

Comment: Provide us the create and insert statement.its very easy to do.

Comment: why Jhon appear only twice if are 3 of those? Why Jessy doesnt appear? Please explain your logic. What mean duplicate? Only name? gender and age too?

Comment: John appear twice is because union will not allow to have duplicate values. From the union i only want to allow duplicate to appear like   Jessy does not hae duplicate so it should appear. Duplicate after the union based on name only. not for age, gender and id.

Comment: Explain the logic you need no what UNION does.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a subquery to get Name which is display more than one,
then self join the table by name again.

You can try this.

```
With T as (
    select ID, Name, Age, Sex from A       
    union 
    select ID, Name, Age, Sex from B
) 
SELECT t2.* FROM 
(
SELECT NAME,COUNT(1) FROM T
GROUP BY Name
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
) t1 INNER JOIN T t2 ON t1.NAME = t2.Name
```

*sqlfiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7c3fb/49*

Answer (score 0):

Why James is not part of the final result you expected?

Anyway, this could be what you looking for:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.ID, a.Name, a.Age, a.Sex
FROM tableA a
JOIN  tableB b ON a.Name = b.Name
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT a.ID, a.Name, a.Age, a.Sex
FROM tableB a
JOIN  tableA b ON a.Name = b.Name
```

Comment: Jame is not in final result expected as it only appear once in Name. if we have 2 row for James then  it should appear too. If 1 row only it should not appear

Answer (score 0):

This would first do a `union` operation and then later group by and select the records which are duplicates.

```
With abc as (
    select ID, Name, Age, Sex from Table A        union 
    select ID, Name, Age, Sex from Table B
) select * from abc where name in (select name from abc group by name having count(*) >1) ;
```

[Sql Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6d0d83/26)